# Unusual Output from C Array Code

Tags: c, arrays

As a simple attempt at a coding exercise in a book I've been reading, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        double data[12][5];
        int i;
        double t = 2.0;

        for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                data[i][0] = t;
                t += 0.1;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                data[i][1] = 1.0 / data[i][0];
                data[i][2] = data[i][0] * data[i][0];
                data[i][3] = data[i][2] * data[i][0];
                data[i][4] = data[i][3] * data[i][0];
        }

        printf("x 1/x x^2 x^3 x^4\n");

        int row;
        int column;

        for(row = 0; row < 12; row++) {
            printf("%10lf %10lf %10lf %10lf %10lf\n", data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

However, when I run it the output appears as at ideone.com: http://ideone.com/KLWtdk. According to how I think the code should run, the far left column should be a range of values inclusive from 2.0 to 3.0 with a 0.1 step size. This is not the case, however.

Also, while chatting on IRC, I was told to not use tabs when printing tables of data but instead to use printf widths. I want to be able to have a header over each column in text, however - is there any way to do that?

Comment: The way to get the labels aligned is `printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n", "x", "1/x", "x^2", "x^3", "x^4");`   Use the same width in the string formats as in the numeric formats.  This right justifies the labels; to left justify, use `%-10s` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you mind if I incorporate your suggestion into my answer (with attribution of course) for the sake of completeness?

Comment: @shree.pat18: go for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you declare iteration variable `row`, but use `i` for index in the print statement. Since the value of `i` is independent of the value of `row`, every iteration will give you the same values, and they won't be the right ones.

You can resolve this by accessing the array elements as `data[row][column_index]` e.g. `data[row][0]`

Regarding the formatting, as mentioned by @JonathanLeffler:

The way to get the labels aligned is

```
printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n", "x", "1/x", "x^2", "x^3", "x^4");
```

Use the same width in the string formats as in the numeric formats. This right justifies the labels; to left justify, use `%-10s` instead.

Comment: @useanalias actually it's afternoon in Singapore

Answer (score 0):

In the last loop you use different variable for iteration and different for printing values. variable `i` used for declaration,condition check & increments/decrements.

`i is that variable.`

Another variable `row` used for printing values which have garbage value and not changed throughout the loop.

`row is that variable`

Answer (score -1):

Use `data[row][0], data[row][1], data[row][2], data[row][3]` while printing results.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but may be because you haven't provided an explanation of why your answer will solve the issue.